# Which linear region should be considered in a Tauc plot when two appear, the one closer to the origin, the one farther away, or both?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, semiconductor-physics, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, absorption

I am analyzing the band gap of $\rm TiO_2$ samples made by ALD and titanium anodization. My doubt is that in the samples made by titanium anodization, two linear regions appear in the [Tauc plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tauc_plot), and I am unsure if this results in two different band gaps because the sample contains both crystalline and amorphous phases; or if I should only consider one of the linear regions. I have tried to find literature that explains the physics behind the Tauc plot in depth, but I have not found much information. In other words, my question is, which linear region should be considered when two appear, the one closer to the origin, the one farther away, or both?